# use the jQuery to draggable or maybe called droppable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Things like this.
Two contains,the right contain is the one who will choose their favorite items,and then use the mouse to choose some,and put the right items to the left contain.Those items can't beyond these two contains.And some style will not change,like margin.To me,I first think use the jQuery UI,but after reading the ui.jquery.com,I get nothing only draggable and droppable.Things like not good to me.
see my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
       .seven-first {
            width: 48px;
            text-align: right;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 22px;
        }
        span.selected {
            display: inline;
            width: 306px;
            height: 178px;
            background: #fbfbfb;
            float: left;
        }
        .bock {
            float:left; display: inline;
            width: 18px; height: 30px;
            margin: 75px 20px auto 23px;
        }
        .seven-right {
            float: left; display: inline; position: relative;
        }
        .seven-right span {
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        .seven-right .second {
            width: 290px; 
            height: 84px;
            margin-left: 24px;
        }
        .seven-right .second b {
            margin-top: 12px;
            display: inline-block;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        .seven-right .second .tag {
            float: left; 
            list-style: none;
            width: 223px;
            margin-top: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            *margin-top: -20px;
        }
        .seven-right .second .tag li {
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin: 0 10px 10px auto;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        .seven-right .second .tag span {
            padding-top: 2px;
        }
        .seven-right .second .tag li span {
            width: auto; 
            margin-right: auto;
            text-align: left; 
        }
        div.noexist {
            float: left;
            margin-top: 13px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="../jquery-1.10.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="seven">
            <span class="seven-first clear">all need</span>
            <span class="selected"></span>
            <span class="bock"></span>
            <span class="clear selected seven-right">
                <span class="second">
                    <b>choose:</b> 
                    <ul class="tag">
                        <li><span>html5</span></li>
                        <li><span>css3</span></li>
                        <li><span>jQuery</span></li>
                        <li><span>PHP</span></li>
                        <li><span>Python</span></li>
                        <li><span>Java</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </span> 
                <div class="noexist">
                    <span>no?</span>
                    <input id="" name="" type="text" /><a href="#">add on</a>
                </div>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

drag the item from right contain and drop them on the left contain,and the other place can't provide the place them.Help me, give me some suggestion! jQuery to me don't so easy.

the code this http://jsfiddle.net/Jackyhua/FgtrW/

Comment: go thru http://jqueryui.com/draggable/  here u find good example with sample code

Comment: with the tutoals, after drag element to the new contain,the contain changes, is there a method to make the contain changeless

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jackyhua/FgtrW/